# please help me with image.GetThumbnailImage (it create very low quality image)

Tags: asp.net, image, thumbnails, system.drawing

i use this code to create thumbnails

```
System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort abort = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(this.ThumbnailCallback);
System.Drawing.Image image2 = image.GetThumbnailImage((int)Math.Round((double)wid / difference), (int)Math.Round((double)hei / difference), abort, IntPtr.Zero);
image2.Save(str2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
image2.Dispose();
```

but i get this very low quality image

[image]

but it is suposed to be like this one

[image]

what i am making wrong
or how can achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not really with the `GetThumbnailImage()` method, but instead in how you are saving the file. You need to specify the quality level of the JPEG you are saving, or it seems it always defaults to a very low value.

Consider this code as a guide (it's from an old .NET 2.0 project; the code still works fine compiled against 4.0, but there may be a more direct method in 4.0; I've never had reason to check)

```
ImageCodecInfo[] encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
ImageCodecInfo jpegEncoder = null;
for (int x = 0; x < encoders.Length; x++) {
    if (string.Compare(encoders[x].MimeType, "image/jpeg", true) == 0) {
        jpegEncoder = encoders[x];
        break;
    }
}
if (jpegEncoder == null) throw new ApplicationException("Could not find JPEG encoder!");
EncoderParameters prms = new EncoderParameters(1);
prms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 80L);
bitmap.Save(fileName, jpegEncoder, prms);
```

Comment: thanks - i will give it a try when i m near my PC and will send u aagain - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that should always work without fetching out the encoder. It resizes keeping relation between width & heigh ... modify for your needs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Resize an image with high quality
/// </summary>
public static Image ResizeImage(Image srcImage, int width)
{
    var b = new Bitmap(width, srcImage.Height * width / srcImage.Width);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(srcImage, 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height);
    }
    return b;
}
```